# Apply same common header to distinct fields of dataframes in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, header

I want to apply a same common header to all dataframes I generate. The application must know which ones have to change/add/remove and in which position.

The distinct dataframes come with different column order, some columns left, some columns added. What I want is:

- If there are more columns than the common common header, these ones will be removed.
- If some column(s) left, add the columns left and fill in the rows with null values

// df with common header to apply

```
val mainDF = Seq(("a","b","c","d","e")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
mainDF.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d|    e|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

// Case 1: distinct column order

```
val df1 = Seq(("a", "c","b","d","e")).toDF("first","third","second","fourth","fifth")
df1.show()

+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|first|third|second|fourth|fifth|
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|    a|    c|     b|     d|    e|
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
```

// Result desired:

```
val df1_correct = Seq(("a","b","c","d","e")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
df1_correct.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d|    e|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

// Case 2: columns left

```
val df2 =  Seq(("a", "b","c","d")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth")
df2.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+
|first|second|third|fourth|
+-----+------+-----+------+
|    a|     b|    c|     d|
+-----+------+-----+------+
```

// Result desired:

```
val df2_correct = Seq(("a","b","c","d","null")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
df2_correct.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d| null|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

// Case 3: columns added

```
val df3 =  Seq(("a", "b","c","d","e","f")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth")
df3.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|sixth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d|    e|    f|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

// Result desired:

```
val df3_correct = Seq(("a","b","c","d","e")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
df3_correct.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d|    e|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

// case 4: distinct column order and e.g a column left

```
val df4 = 
Seq(("a", "c","b","d")).toDF("first","third","second","fourth")
df4.show()

+-----+-----+------+------+
|first|third|second|fourth|
+-----+-----+------+------+
|    a|    c|     b|     d|
+-----+-----+------+------+
```

// Result desired:

```
val df4_correct = Seq(("a","b","c","d","null")).toDF("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
df4_correct.show()

+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     b|    c|     d| null|
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover all your cases:

```
val selectExp = mainDF.columns.map( c => if(df4.columns.contains(c)) col(c) 
                                         else lit(null).as(c) )
```

You `map` over `mainDF.columns` which is an `Array[String]` of the column names of `mainDF`

```
Array[String] = Array(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
```

Replace `df4` with whichever dataframe you want to generate expression for. If the column in `dfx` matches with `mainDF`, then select it, otherwise generate a `null` with the column name fetched from `mainDF`

You will get a `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]`

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(first, second, third, fourth, NULL AS `fifth`)
```

which you can use on the `df` as

```
df4.select(selectExp : _*).show

//+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
//|first|second|third|fourth|fifth|
//+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
//|    a|     b|    c|     d| null|
//+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much @philantrovert I cannot give you points as I do not have enough reputation yet. It works!